# Azure - Grant resource access to an external application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an application that I registered in my Azure portal, which requires permissions to access Azure Service Management API. In order for it to work with Azure resources, I need to add a role assignment to a subscription for my application, to be able, for example, to make an API call such as this:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourcegroups?api-version=2017-05-10
```

I want to have my app work with different Azure portals.
My question is - how do I add a role assignment for my app on an another Azure AD that doesn't have my app registered, but has given consent to it? Am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I add a role assignment for my app on an another Azure AD that doesn't have my app registered, but has given consent to it?

Yes, you can.

When the app has been consent in your another tenant, azure will create an enterprise application for your app registration in that tenant, you can find in the `Azure Active Directory` -> `Enterprise applications`(search with `All Applications`).

To add the assignment for it, just need to navigate to the `Subscription` in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> add your Enterprise application(service principal) as a role e.g. `Owner`/`Contributor`.

Then you can use the [`client credentials flow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) to get the access token for your service principal, the `client_secret` is the one in your first tenant. Then you can use the token to call the rest api in your question.

Update:

I do not recommend you to use User Account to get access token. Because when you enable MFA, you could not use UserCredential to get. If you use Visual Studio, you could use `AzureServiceTokenProvider` to get access token.

```
 var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
 string accessToken =  azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com");
```

BTW, I still suggest you to use service principal which has existing in subscription to get access token, so that you could use the flow you use before.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try it. Is it possible to do this by API call as well?

Comment: Yes, you can [grant access](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest#grant-access) role to subscription with `subscriptions/{subscriptionId1}` as scope.

Comment: I couldn't grant access for the subscription ID with the token I got from the client credentials authentication... It's some sort of a paradox where you have to have access in order to give access. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Because the app you get token is not added into the subscription.

Comment: You need to use user account or service principal which has existing in subscription with owner role to get access token and then grant access.

Comment: Why do you need to achieve it through api call? It's easy to do it with portal.

Comment: I'm looking to automate it without UI interaction. So I need to execute this call with a user that has an appropriate role? Which auth flow would that be?

Comment: I have update my reply, if it helps you, please accept it as answer.

Comment: My case would be that I will not have an existing service principal. What would be the best way then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201581/discussion-between-joey-cai-and-user6251216).